# RequireJS + Mocha + JSDom + Node -> Shim config not supported in Node

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, requirejs, amd, jsdom

I'm trying to setup a Mocha testing framework using JSDom with RequireJS. Because I'm running the test on node instead of using a browser (since I'm using JSDom), all the non AMD modules doesn't seem to be imported and is throwing `Shim config not supported in Node`. Does anyone know how I can export those modules to AMD or what the right approach is? (aka what I'm doing wrong)

Example of my set-up

*Component.js*

```
define(["jquery", "non_AMD_Module", ... ], function($, NonAMDModule, ...) {
  let component = {
    ...
    foo = () => {
      NonAMDModule.bar();
    };
  };
  return component;
});
```

*Component.test.js*

```
const requirejs = require('requirejs');
const { JSDOM }  = require('jsdom');

requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "dist/app",
  paths: {
    jquery: "lib/jquery",
    component: "path_to_component",
    non_AMD_Module: "path_to_module"
  },
  shim: {
    non_AMD_Module: { exports: "non_AMD_Module" } // This doesn't work
  }
});

const { window } = new JSDOM("<html></html>");
global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.$ = requirejs('jquery');

const Component = requireJS('component');
describe('test', () => {
  it('is a simple test', () => {
     const testComponent = new Component();
     testComponent.foo();
  }
});
```

When I run the test suite, I get:

```
Mocha Exploded!
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
```

running `r.js -convert "path_to_module"` did not work for this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for jQuery, I found that there's this boiler-plate coded that exports it to AMD.

This can be added at the bottom of the non-AMD-module in order to export it to an AMD module accessible by RequireJS

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
  define([], function {
    return non_AMD_Module;
  });
}
```

Other Resources:

[Shim a module in Require.js that uses module.exports possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133879/shim-a-module-in-require-js-that-uses-module-exports-possible)

https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/wiki/Updating-existing-libraries#anon